# Importance of time in training a model

Tags: predictive-modeling

Does the time taken to train a model an important factor of consideration in data science? since models are trained once then applied to predict new data, does it matter if model A takes longer time than model B to train on training dataset but during prediction of new data records, both the time taken is similar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The time it takes to train a model is one of several things to consider when choosing among models. Due to "concept drift" and "data drift", it's rarely the case that you only train the model once. Both the input data and target variable can change over time which can make your model perform significantly worse if not continuously retrained. Additionally, you might collect more data over time which you might want to include in order to get the best possible model.

How often you retrain the model depends a lot (but not necessarily uniquely) on how much it drifts over time and how much additional data you collect.

Found [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/data-drift-in-depth-understanding-rishabh-bhatia) that explains drift more in depth.

Comment: would hyperparameter tuning be avoided then as it usually takes longer time than not utilizing hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: This might depend on how much drift you experience and will most certainly depend on whether new features are incorporated into the model. In general though, you can use the same best hyperparameters for retraining (assuming you've tuned it before and that there's only little drift and no new features).